# Angular - How to get nested component reference?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 5.2.2 and I'd like to know if it's possible to find a descendant component **(nesting depth 2+)**.

For example:

- FirstLevelComponent **(Declared in my Application)**
- SecondLevelComponent **(Third party component)**
- ThirdLevelComponent **(Third party component)**

**FirstLevelComponent Template**:

```
<first-level-component>
   <second-level-component></second-level-component>
</first-level-component>
```

**SecondLevelComponent Template**:

```
<third-level-component></third-level-component>
```

I'd like to get ThirdLevelComponent instance in the FirstLevelComponent.

- I've tried using @ViewChildren and @ContentChildren, but no success. Both returns an empty QueryList.
- **I can't change SecondLevelComponent** code to expose the ThirdLevelComponent because it's a third party component.

This plunker demonstrates what I'm trying to do: https://plnkr.co/edit/9NsYmrsJMJEi0wofQReI?p=preview

---

**EDIT (2018/02/06)**

- One option could be inheriting SecondLevelComponent for exposing ThirdLevelComponent, but I wouldn't like to use inheritance and it would be limited to just one more depth level.
- After some inspecting, I endend up creating a helper that searches for descendants components. It uses ViewContainerRef:

  ```
    import * as NgCore from '@angular/core';

  @NgCore.Injectable()
  export class FindDescendantsService {
      constructor() { }
      private findRecursive(container: any, type: any, results: any[]) {
          if (!container) { return; }
          if ('nodes' in container) {
              container.nodes.forEach(n => {
                  if ('componentView' in n && n.componentView) {
                      if (n.componentView.component instanceof type) {
                          results.push(n.componentView.component);
                      }
                      this.findRecursive(n.componentView, type, results);
                      return;
                  }

                  if ('viewContainer' in n && n.viewContainer && n.viewContainer._embeddedViews && n.viewContainer._embeddedViews.length) {
                      n.viewContainer._embeddedViews.forEach(v => this.findRecursive(v, type, results));
                      return;
                  }
              });
          }
      }
      find(vcr: NgCore.ViewContainerRef, type: any) {
          var view = vcr['_view'];
          var results = [];
          this.findRecursive(view, type, results);
          return results;
      }
  }
  ```

Then in FirstLevelComponent I can do:

```
ngAfterContentInit(){    
   var thirdLevelInstances = this.findDescendantsService.find(this.viewContainerRef, ThirdLevelComponent);
}
```

I'm not very comfortable because it uses some private variables that might change names/behaviour in future releases of angular, but this satisfy my goal for now. I'll wait some time to see if a better solution appears, if not, I think this helper might be the answer...

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, `second component` should have an instance of `third component`. E.g.

```
// First Component
@Component({
    selector: 'first-comp',
    template: `<second-comp></second-comp>`
})
export class FirstComponent {
    @ViewChild(SecondComponent) secondComponent: SecondComponent;

    doSomething() {
         this.secondComponent.thirdComponent.doStuff();
    }
}

// Second Component
@Component({
    selector: 'second-comp',
    template: `<third-comp></third-comp>`
})
export class SecondComponent{
    @ViewChild(ThirdComponent) thirdComponent: ThirdComponent;
}  

// Third Component
@Component({
    selector: 'third-comp',
    template: `<div>Hello World</div>`
})
export class ThirdComponent{
    doStuff() {
       // some logic here
    }
}
```

However, I would not recommend this method. This creates tightly coupled components which is harder to test as well. You should always pass your data through `@Input` and `@Output`s or some services.

Answer (score 1):

In angular communication between components is only father/son. If you can't use second-level-component, you could accomplish this by using a service, as is recommended in the docs.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

With angular 13 (Maybe before but i've not tested) you can add an option in `@ContentChildren` `descendants:true`

For you example it will look like that

```js
  @ContentChildren(ThirdLevelComponent, {descendants: true})
  thirdLevelComponents : QueryList<ThirdLevelComponent>;
```